# Backtracking Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, backtracking

I have a system that controls a medical office agenda. I need to use the backtracking algorithm if the doctor cancel the appointments of the day. The algorithm must reschedule the cancelled appointments in another date and hour, based on the preferences of patients schedules (week day and hour). It must return true just if all the cancelled appointments were rescheduled. If one or more fails it must try again until there's no solution left. Can anyone explain me how I should use the algorithm to solve this? Or give me some helpful links? I'm trying search for it on google and here but with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding what backtracking is and how it works, or are you only having trouble figuring out how to write code for it?

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand how it should work for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this pseudo-code will help:

```
boolean schedule (array-of-appointments-to-reschedule, calendar-with-available-times) {
    for each possible TIME where array-of-appointments[FIRST] can fit into
          calendar-with-available-times {
        if (array-of-appointments has only 1 element)
            return true;  // we've succeeded
        success = schedule (array-of-appointments-WITHOUT-the-first-one,
                            calendar-with-available-time with TIME blocked out);
            // this is the backtracking part, we call schedule recursively on the
            // _remaining_ appointments, and if we can't fit the rest of the           
            // appointments, then backtrack and try the next TIME
        if (success) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't quite do everything, since it doesn't actually keep track of the successful results, but hopefully it will get you started.